# Find Row In R If Value Of Two Cells Matches

Tags: r, package

Using R, I want to find the `row number` based on whether two cell values in the given row matches.

Below code tells me the output value is true, but I was expecting the `row number` for the matched cell.

```
> which(Data[1, 2] == 2 & Data[1,3] == 3)
[1] 1
```

Is this the correct approach? If not, please suggest better method to find the `row number` given the two cells holds comparing value. Thanks.

Comment: Your code only compares the first row, so the answer will always be 1 or nothing.  To compare them all, `which(Data[, 2] == 2 & Data[,3] == 3)` should do it. Provide a reproducible example with desired result for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RichScriven answered this in comment section above.

Solution:

```
> which(Data[, 2] == 2 & Data[,3] == 3)
[1] 40
```